# Are there cases where It.IsAny does not match a value?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, prism

I use the Moq library to mock interfaces provided by the Prism library in my MVVM WPF project in order to unit-test them as part of my viewmodel. Specifically I have a viewmodel which uses Prisms `IDialogService`.

I want to unit test whether executing a specific command opens a specific dialogue with specific parameters. Here is what I did to do this:

```
 // Arrange

 var mockDialogService = new Mock<IDialogService>();
 var viewModel = SetupViewModel(mockDialogService.Object);

 // Act

 viewModel.OpenNewStockDialogueCommand.Execute();

 // Assert

 mockDialogService.Verify(s => s.ShowDialog(
   It.IsAny<string>(),
   It.IsAny<IDialogParameters>(),
   It.IsAny<Action<IDialogResult>>()),
   Times.Once);
```

The relevant part is happening in the Assert section of my test. The `ShowDialog` method takes the following arguments:

1. name: `string`
2. parameters: `IDialogParameters`
3. callback: `Action<IDialogResult>`

[Here is some documentation on the Prism Dialogservice, for those interested](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dialogs/dialog-service.html)

Now, as far as I understand it, if I call the `ShowDialog` method, before calling the `Verify` method, regardless of which parameters I actually pass into it, the `Verify` method should complete without exception. As you probably guessed by me being on the forum, it does actually throw an exception however and presents me with the following message:

```
Message: 
    Moq.MockException : 
    Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: s => s.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DialogParameters>(), It.IsAny<Action<IDialogResult>>())
    
    Performed invocations:
    
       Mock<IDialogService:1> (s):
    
          IDialogService.Show("NewStockDialogue", ?CurrentStock=FHAA.Stock, Action<IDialogResult>)
```

So there you go. This is very strange to me. It seems that the method does in fact get called, as indicated by the "Performed Invocation" but something about the parameters is not matching. Does somebody have an idea why?

It is also important to note that I dont actually want to put `It.IsAny` here, I actually have some semi-fixed values I want to test for, but since it does not event work with `It.IsAny`, what hope do I have to get it working with restrictions.

Thank you so much for your time, your help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT

Turns out I was actually testing `IDialogService.Show` instead of `ShowDialog`. This was the problem

```
dialogService.Show(DialogueNames.NewStock, parameters, OnNewStockDialogueClosed);
```

Comment: Expected `ShowDialog` actually invoked `Show`. So it would appear you are verifying a different member to what called.

Comment: Expectation also includes  `It.IsAny<DialogParameters>()`. is that a typo where it should have been `It.IsAny<IDialogParameters>()` (note the interface)

Comment: @Nkosi, that is true, I did not notice that. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nkosi already pointed out, you are calling the `Show` method, but verify if `ShowDialog` was called. That is clearly stated in the error message. Decide which one you want to use and adapt the test or view model.

> It is also important to note that I dont actually want to put It.IsAny here, I actually have some semi-fixed values I want to test for [...]

You can check conditions on the parameters with `It.Is<T>`, not with `It.IsAny<T>`. You just have to pass an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, which is an expression of a predicate. This predicate checks the corresponding parameter for correctness and returns the result as `bool`. Look at this example.

```
viewModel.ShowDialog("My dialog name", new DialogParameters {{"Key 1", "Value 1"}}, result => testInt = 32);
```

I called this `ShowDialog` in a view model. I can verify, if the parameters are correct like this.

```
var expectedDialogParameters = new DialogParameters {{ "Key 1", "Value 1" }};
mockDialogService.Verify(s => s.ShowDialog(
   It.Is<string>(name => name == "My dialog name"),
   It.Is<DialogParameters>(dialogParameters => dialogParameters.SequenceEqual(expectedDialogParameters)),
   It.IsAny<Action<IDialogResult>>()),
   Times.Once);
```

For the name of the dialog I just check for `string` equality in a lambda. For the dialog parameters I use an instance of my expected dialog parameters. I compare the `DialogParameters` with `SequenceEqual`, because they are implemented as `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`, so a list of key value pairs. I cannot use `Equals`, because it is not overridden in `DialogParameters` and would only check for *reference equality*, which would fail. Furthermore, use `DialogParameters` in `It.Is`. `IDialogParameters` is just an interface for `DialogParameters` that does **not** implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`, so you would not be able to compare with `SequenceEqual`. Last but not least, you *could* validate the dialog result action, but that might not be easy. You could instead check in your view model, what changed due to the action being executed.

Comment: Yes, I did in fact test IDialogService.Show. My bad. I am a fool. Should I just delete the question since nothing can be actually learned from it?